# Terminal can't install something named libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

My configuration is amd64, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Since days I'm trying to install openFrameworks on my fresh Ubuntu (http://openframeworks.cc/download/).

```
Installing libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04'
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04 »
error installing libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04
Lecture des listes de paquets… 
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances…
Lecture des informations d'état…
this seems an error with your distribution repositories
```

So I've investigated via openFrameworks forums and found the file can be downloaded here:https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libgl1-mesa-dev
But after this installation I still get the same message in the Terminal.
Is there something I'm missing?
Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you answers yes on the question `installing OF dependencies...`? try answering no. https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/scripts/linux/ubuntu/install_dependencies.sh#L122

Comment: You are looking for the package `libgl1-mesa-dev-hwe-16.04`, not for the package `libgl1-mesa-dev`. Remind that a fresh install of 16.04.2 comes with HWE. You will probably find this package in the 16.10 repository. Check out [here](http://openframeworks.cc/setup/linux-install/) and look for `Install on Third-Party Linux Distribution`.

Comment: Having the same issue - any update?

Comment: Opened an Issue here: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/5496

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look into the "install_dependencies.sh" , you will see "-hwe-16.04" extension is defined by the "XTAG" variable and it used only for mesa lib (which is "free implementation of the OpenGL API"). Above the 16.04 (16.04.1, 16.04.2) you don't need this special version anymore. So when you run "install_dependencies.sh" (without the "-y" switch) simply answer "no" to the question :   "installing OF dependencies with -hwe-16.04 packages, confirm Y/N ?"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Answer (score -1):

They might have removed the 16.04 specific driver.

Try `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev`, as that is a package which I assume is the same thing.

Also, you may need some other package, so run `apt-cache search libgl1-mesa` and see if that matches any other packages that might be relevant.